# Replacing all the instances of a given character in a string except when it is framed by an other specific character

Tags: string, postgresql, replace

I'm looking for a simple/performant/elegant way for replacing all the instances of a given charater within a string except when it is framed by an other specific charater. As an Example :

I want to replace in the string `a,b,c,"d,e,f,g",h,i,j` all the `,` characters by `#` except when they are framed by `"`. The expected result is : `a#b#c#"d,e,f,g"#h#i#j`.

Any idea welcomed.

Comment: I suggest fixing your data outside of Postgres and then reimporting.

Comment: I have to convert the data in postgres before exporting them to another application ...

Comment: You will need to provide some more details. Are there ALWAYS exactly two double-quote characters in each string? Never one or three or zero?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion as a PL/pgSQL block that - if relevant - can be amended/shaped as a function.
Basically it extracts, stores and replaces the "immune" parts of the string (these enclosed in double quotes), replaces the commas with hashes and then replaces back the "immune" parts. `IMMUNE_PATTERN` may need to be amended too.

```sql
do language plpgsql
$$
declare
    target_text text := 'a,b,c,"d,e,f,g",h,i,"d2,e2,f2,g2",j'::text;
    IMMUNE_PATTERN constant text := '__%s__';
    immune_parts text[];
    immune text;
    i integer;
begin
    immune_parts := array(select * from regexp_matches(target_text,'"[^"]+"','g'));

    for immune, i in select * from unnest(immune_parts) with ordinality loop 
        target_text := replace(target_text, immune, format(IMMUNE_PATTERN, i));
    end loop;

    target_text := replace(target_text, ',', '#');

    for immune, i in select * from unnest(immune_parts) with ordinality loop 
        target_text := replace(target_text, format(IMMUNE_PATTERN, i), immune);
    end loop;

    raise notice '%',  target_text;
end;
$$;
```

The result is that
`a,b,c,"d,e,f,g",h,i,"d2,e2,f2,g2",j` becomes
`a#b#c#"d,e,f,g"#h#i#"d2,e2,f2,g2"#j`